# Heroku pipeline drops buildpack settings for Review Apps

Tags: heroku, heroku-pipelines

I'm currently using Heroku Pipeline feature for automatically detecting, building and deploying pull requests for review.

> ✓ Create new review apps for new pull requests automatically
>
> URL pattern
> Pattern: Random pipeline-xxxxxx-xxxxxx.herokuapp.com

The problem is that my app needs a combination of 2 buildpacks in a specific order in order to boot properly.

The main/production app has this settings and it works fine(e.g. after each time a PR is merged).

From what I see Review Apps doesn't have a concept of buildpack settings and it tries to autodetect it each time.

What I've tried:

Open the latest Review App, set buildpacks, rebuild or push a new commit. It works fine in that Pull Request/branch/Review App but for each new PR this process has to be repeated manually.

Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a similar issue, one approach that you can use(that worked for me)

`app.json` [Heroku's convention file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema) where you can list your buildpacks among many other settings.

Comment: Could you please post a working app.json? I'm trying to set this up but Heroku appears to be ignoring my app.json file

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem. setting buildpacks to app.json worked once but new review apps are still failing